# Chain rule (hopefully simple question?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am trying to find the following partial derivative.

$$\frac {\partial }{\partial Y} U(Y-T(Y))$$

I know I need to use the chain rule, and if the function were simply U(T(Y)) it would obviously be straightforward - but I'm getting caught up on subtracting a function of Y from Y directly. Does anyone have any guidance on where to start here? (Also, I'm new to MathJax so let me know if I should make edits to make that better!)

Thanks all.

Comment: It is not clear what you are deriving?

Comment: Maybe I should change my notation? I'm trying to find the partial derivative of U with respect to Y, when U is a function of both Y and T(Y).

Comment: Maybe you mean $\frac {\partial }{\partial Y} U(Y-T(Y))$?

Comment: Ok. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$U=U(Y-T(Y))$$

then

$$\frac {\partial }{\partial Y} U(Y-T(Y))=U'(Y-T(Y))\cdot \frac {\partial }{\partial Y}(Y-T(Y))=U'(Y-T(Y))\cdot(1-T'(Y))$$

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense! I was clearly just making it too complicated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @G.VanHorn You are welcome! It could be useful try to calculate if for some concrete example. Bye

Comment: I don't think $U = f(Y-T(Y))$ is what you wanted, because what is $U(Y-T(Y))$ then? I don't see why you need to introduce $f$ at all.

Comment: @Ennar You are right it is not necessary, but in that way it seems more clear to stress the fact that U is some function of $(Y+T(Y))$. Of course we can use directly U without introducing f.

Comment: But I wouldn't say $U$ is a function of $(Y-T(Y))$. It is some function $U\colon A\to B$, and if $Y-T(Y)$ is in $A$, then $U(Y-T(Y))$ is in $B$. I just find the notation confusing, I would interpret your $f$ to be a function $f\colon A\to B^A$.

Comment: @Ennar I don't understand exactly your doubt on that but I can try to eliminate the f.

Comment: Well, my doubt is the same as in what is notationally function: $f$ or $f(x)$? We often interchange these two things, but changing $U$ to $f$ confused me. Thanks for accommodating me.

Comment: @Ennar You are welcome! Thanks to have kindly pointed out that issue to me! Cheers